# In windows How get all process and their child process information in command prompt in windows 7

Tags: windows

In windows Tasklist is the command but how list the Running process and their child process in windows 7

Answer (score 30):

You can get a list of processes with the PID and parent PID using:

```
wmic process get Caption,ParentProcessId,ProcessId
```

Given a parent PID you can list the *immediate* children with something like:

```
wmic process where (ParentProcessId=2480) get Caption,ProcessId
```

Comment: Example has incorrect where clause formatting. It actually shall be with parenthesis
  
`wmic process where ("ParentProcessId=2480") get Caption,ProcessId`