# NodeJS child process PID does not match the real process

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb, batch-file, pid

I'm using windows, and I'm doing this experiment,

```
console.log( _.process.exec( "mongod --dbpath . --port 8083 --bind_ip 127.0.0.1" ).pid );
```

The problem is, when I do a tasklist command, the PID from that output points to the command prompt task and not to the mongod.exe task.

Is there a way to get the real PID of the mongod.exe task?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mongod` is a child process of `cmd` and `tasklist` doesn't print child process `id`s.

Given a parent process id, you can get a list of it's children with a [`wmi query`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620295/303270):

```
wmic process where (ParentProcessId=CMD_PID) get Caption, ProcessId
```

Replace `CMD_PID` with the parent(cmd) process id.

Comment: I see the child process via tasklist.exe.  Not sure how to grab that and use it within the Node app though.  I need to kill it by PID later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this now and thinking that I'll need to run process.pid in the child and signal it back to the parent. The parent then needs to keep track of the number in case the child needs to be killed.

I was hoping this wouldn't be so complicated?